# How to download files from Azure Blob Storage with a Download Link

Tags: c#, html, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

I made an Azure Cloud Service, where you can upload and delete files to the cloud storage using Blobs. I wrote sucessfully a method where you can delete the uploaded blobs from the cloud service:

```
 public string DeleteImage(string Name)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(Name);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        blob.Delete();

        return "File Deleted";
    }
}
```

Here is also the code for View with HTML:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<h2>Upload Image</h2>

<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 
"multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
}

</p>

<ul style="list-style-position:Outside;padding:0;">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<li>
    <img src="@item" alt="image here" width="100" height="100" />
    <a id="@item" href="#" onclick="deleteImage ('@item');">Delete</a>

</li>
}
</ul>

<script>
function deleteImage(item) {
    var url = "/Home/DeleteImage";
    $.post(url, { Name: item }, function (data){
        window.location.href = "/Home/Upload";
    });
}

</script>
```

Now I want to write a similiar method so you can download each blob from the View. I tried to write the methode using exactly the same code from the delete but instead of

```
blob.delete();
```

now

```
blob.DownloadToFile(File);
```

This didn't work though. Is there a possibility to change the delete method so it downloads the chosen blob instead of deleting it?

---

### Added Info

Here is the code of DownloadToFile method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public string DownloadImage(string Name)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(Name);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = 
_blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        blob.DownloadToFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);


        return "File Downloaded";
    }
```

The name is just the whole filename that is uploaded. Filename is the data path.

The Exception I get is:

UnauthorizedAccessException: The access to the path "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Eva Passwort.docx" is denied.]

I think that the problem is that my application doesn't have a path to save the file. Is there a possibility to get a dialog where I can chose the path to save?

Comment: Can you share your `DownloadToFile` code ? and mention what error you are getting.

Comment: Please share some examples of "Name" and "fileName", and the details of the exception you met, or we're not able to provide help with current information.

Comment: I posted the DownloadToFile method below.

Answer (score 10):

> I want to write a similiar method so you can download each blob from the View.

It seems that you'd like to enable users to download the blob files, the following sample code work fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
public ActionResult DownloadImage()
{
    try
    {
        var filename = "xxx.PNG";
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connection_string}");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        Stream blobStream = blob.OpenRead();

        return File(blobStream, blob.Properties.ContentType, filename);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //download failed 
        //handle exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note: Detailed information about [Controller.File Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to download the file content directly using the URL? Basically my front end is not based on MVC and I can't create an ActionResult. I just want a simple download URL and may be, if required, pass auth token/key along with the HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to generate a pre-signed URL (one-time link) using a shared access policy and headers. https://medium.com/@harshavardhan.ghorpade/cloud-agnostic-upload-download-apis-using-pre-signed-urls-aws-azure-google-cloud-b99c59ac819d

Answer (score 2):

Using Azure Blob Storage SDK v12

```
new BlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName).DownloadTo(pathToDownload);
```

Reference:
https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/beginners-guide-and-reference-to-azure-blob-storage-sdk-v12-dot-net-csharp/

https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/beginners-guide-and-reference-to-azure-blob-storage-sdk-v12-dot-net-csharp/#download_blob_from_a_container

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it worked great

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using OC3.Core.Model.Server;

namespace OC3.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("v1/desktop/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    public class DownloadController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DownloadController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        // code added by Ameer for downloading the attachment from shipments
        [HttpGet("Attachment")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ActionResultAsync(string filepath)
        {
            ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();

            responseMessage.resultType = "Download";

            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                {
                    responseMessage.totalCount = 1;

                    
                    string shareName = string.Empty;        

                    filepath = filepath.Replace("\\", "/");
                    string fileName = filepath.Split("//").Last();
                    if (filepath.Contains("//"))
                    {
                        //Gets the Folder path of the file.
                        shareName = filepath.Substring(0, filepath.LastIndexOf("//")).Replace("//", "/"); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        responseMessage.result = "File Path is null/incorrect";
                        return Ok(responseMessage);
                    }

                    string storageAccount_connectionString = _configuration["Download:StorageConnectionString"].ToString();
                    // get file share root reference
                    CloudFileClient client = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString).CreateCloudFileClient();
                    CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference(shareName);

                    // pass the file name here with extension
                    CloudFile cloudFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(fileName);


                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await cloudFile.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                    responseMessage.result = "Success";

                    var contentType = "application/octet-stream";

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        return File(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), contentType, fileName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage.result = "File Path is null/incorrect";
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
                {
                    responseMessage.result = ex.Message;
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // if file folder path or file is not available the exception will be caught here
                responseMessage.result = ex.Message;
                return Ok(responseMessage);
            }

            return Ok(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```