# Download file in azure storage using ASP.Net core2

Tags: c#, azure, download, azure-storage, asp.net-core-2.0

I have web application and user should be able to download files which are stored in the azure storage.

```
public class FileDownloader
{
    private string constring = "myconnectionstring";

    public async Task download(string fileName, string directoryName)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(constring);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("myreference");
            string userName = Environment.UserName;


            if (await share.ExistsAsync())
            {
                // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
                CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName);

                // Ensure that the directory exists.
                if (await sampleDir.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                    CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference(fileName);

                    // Ensure that the file exists.
                    if (await file.ExistsAsync())
                    {

                        await file.DownloadToFileAsync(string.Format("C:/Users/" + userName + "/Downloads/{0}", fileName), FileMode.Create);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is my code.

It works perfectly when I run application in my local environment(localhost) but when I deploy it and host it in the azure, it isn't downloading the files.

Comment: Saying *it isn't downloading the files* doesn't help us at all. In what way does it fail? Do you get error messages? If so, what are they? Have you tried debugging? Is your code failing somewhere?

Comment: Also, if you're hosting this in Azure, where do you think `C:/Users......` will point at there?

Comment: What is the proper way to get client's file downloading path

Comment: Do you want to download the file on the client machine? Your code will actually download the file on the server where your code is running (provided the download path you have specified is correct).

Comment: Yes. I want to download files in to the client's machine. how should i do it when i hosted my application on azure

Answer (score 1):

DownloadToFileAsync() : it allows you to download the file in the directory of your application not client.

May be use a stream to download it ?

[How to download files from Azure Blob Storage with a Download Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442818/how-to-download-files-from-azure-blob-storage-with-a-download-link)